# Using JQuery and php to fetch data from a mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to retrive data from a db. I'm using jquery and php

this is my code

```
$('input#barcode1').on('blur', function(){
    var barcode = $('input#barcode1').val();
    if(barcode!='')
    {
        $.post('ajax/prodotto.php', {name: barcode}, function(data){
            $('input#prodotto1').val(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Now it works perfectly (i.e. I can see in the form the result) if the data I must retrive is numeric (like price etc), but it doesn't work if I must retrieve a string (like for example a name of a product like "coca cola")

here my php code

```
       <?php

        if(isset( $_POST['name'])===true && empty($_POST['name'])===false){
        require '../db/connect.php';

        $query=mysql_query("
           SELECT prodotto as prodotto
         FROM prodotti_bar
         WHERE barcode='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'");

          echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0)? mysql_result($query, 0,   'prodotto') : 'prodotto not found';
       }
      ?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please add the relevant PHP code, too.

Comment: What do you mean "*it doesn't work*"? Does the query succeed but fails in retrieving proper data? Do you have any errors? Have you tried running the query on the mysql server (phpmyadmin)?

Comment: "it doesn't work" means that I don't see an output in the form. I have a form where a put a barcode and it retrieve the barcode in a db, and I want to see the name of the product (but i don't see it) and the price of the product (i see it)

Comment: As always with AJAX the first thing is to use your browser's developer tool network tab to see what call you are sending & response you are getting. It's much easier to track down the issues that way.

Comment: sorry  Tom Toms but I don't know ho to do it...:-(

Comment: >You should really stop using MySQL_* functions. This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is a space between "coca" and "cola" ==> "coca cola".

Maybe the issue is you need to url encode

> Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

Example:

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);
```

would produce "coca+cola"  or "coca%20cola" that will ensure the string is properly passed to server-side.

Comment: thanks jasonlam604 but i tried with a normal word like "aaaa" and th result was the same...nothings appears...

Comment: SOLVED: i do a mistake in the form...assuming that the field "prodotto" was number and not text...thanks to all